# How to use print command with loops in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, matlab-figure

I have looked up this simple question regarding printing graphs in Matlab without success so far. I have a for loop of this type:

```
N = 5;
for sim = 1:10
  X = randn(sim,N);
  X = mean(X);

  figure;
  plot(X);
  print -depsc X;
end
```

I would like to print and save one new graph for each simulation, and automatically name it, for example, X1 for sim = 1, X2 for sim = 2, X3 for sim = 3, etc. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
N = 5;
for sim = 1:10
  X = randn(sim,N);
  X = mean(X);

  hFig = figure;
  plot(X);

  % create filename and print to eps
  filename = strcat('X',num2str(sim));
  print(hFig,filename,'-depsc');
end
```

Hope this helps!